# Prevent dll from writing too much data into buffer

Tags: c, buffer

I write a program that calls functions from dlls just to fiddle around. I have the following function

```
char *ext(char *buffer, int len) { 

    char *tmp = buffer;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        *(buffer++) = 'A';  
    *buffer++ = '\0';

    return tmp;

}
```

I made a for loop but if someone else write a dll which writes too much data and my program loads it, is there a way to prevent this scenario?

Comment: Do you know big the buffer is other than via `len`? If not, then no.

Comment: you can validate the `len` to a certain number that you think is sufficient. If it goes bigger than this limit, your function can ignore the rest (assuming it won't impact the overall functionality).